# Decimal value rounding upwards

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox, decimal, rounding

I have a textbox into which I want to input decimal numbers. The problem is that the actual number isn't being saved. Instead the inputted number is being rounded upwards. So if I input 1.5, 2.0 is taken in.

**The TextBox that takes in the value**

```
Dim _case As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(txtCase.Text)
```

I've found other rounding issues on SO but none seem to be similar to my problem.
I've also checked the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/decimal-data-type but I don't seem to see anything to have in mind regarding this problem.

**Column to which value should be saved in SQL Server**

[image: Cases]

It's probably something simple but I can't seem to see it.

Any ideas?

**EDIT. Also tried:**

```
Dim _case As String = Convert.ToDecimal(txtCase.Text)
```

**Whole Code**

```
Protected Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddUpdate.Click

    'Constants
    Const _addAdjustmentText As String = "Add Adjustment"
    Const _updateText As String = "Update"

    'Declare the fields
    Dim _refYear As Integer = Integer.Parse(txtRefYear.Text)
    Dim _refMonth As String = ddlMonth.SelectedIndex.ToString()
    Dim _branchCode As String = txtBranchCode.Text
    Dim _employeeCode As String = txtEmployeeCode.Text
    Dim _policyNumber As Long = Long.Parse(txtPolicyNumber.Text)
    Dim _extraPolicyType As String = ddlExtraPolicyType.SelectedIndex.ToString()
    Dim _premium As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(txtPremium.Text)
    Dim _case As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(txtCase.Text)
    Dim _planCode As String = txtPlanCode.Text
    Dim _planDescription As String = txtPlanDescription.Text

    If btnAddUpdate.Text = _addAdjustmentText Then

        Try
            Company.Applications.ProductionEngine.BusinessAccess.ManualAdjustmentsBusinessAccess.InsertNewAdjustment(_refYear,
                                                                                                                      _refMonth,
                                                                                                                      _branchCode,
                                                                                                                      _employeeCode,
                                                                                                                      _policyNumber,
                                                                                                                      _extraPolicyType,
                                                                                                                      _premium,
                                                                                                                      _case,
                                                                                                                      _planCode,
                                                                                                                      _planDescription)
            InformationBox1.ShowSuccessMessage("Adjustment inserted")
            clearAllFields()
            loadManualAdjustments()

        Catch ex As Exception
            InformationBox1.ShowErrorMessage("An internal error occured. Please check values and try again.")

        End Try

    ElseIf btnAddUpdate.Text = _updateText Then

        'Update field based on RowId. txtUpdateRowId Hidden field.
        Dim _rowId As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(txtUpdateRowId.Text.ToString())

        Try
            Company.Applications.ProductionEngine.BusinessAccess.ManualAdjustmentsBusinessAccess.UpdateManualAdjustment(_refYear,
                                                                                                                         _refMonth,
                                                                                                                         _branchCode,
                                                                                                                         _employeeCode,
                                                                                                                         _policyNumber,
                                                                                                                         _extraPolicyType,
                                                                                                                         _premium,
                                                                                                                         _case,
                                                                                                                         _planCode,
                                                                                                                         _planDescription,
                                                                                                                         _rowId)
            InformationBox1.ShowSuccessMessage("Adjustment updated")
            btnAddUpdate.Text = "Add Adjustment"
            clearAllFields()
            loadManualAdjustments()

        Catch ex As Exception
            InformationBox1.ShowErrorMessage("An internal error occured. Please check values and try again.")
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

**Business Layer**

```
Public Shared Function UpdateManualAdjustment(ByVal _refYear As Integer,
                                               ByVal _refMonth As String,
                                               ByVal _branchCode As String,
                                               ByVal _employeeCode As String,
                                               ByVal _policyNumber As Integer,
                                               ByVal _extraPolicyType As String,
                                               ByVal _premium As Integer,
                                               ByVal _case As Decimal,
                                               ByVal _planCode As String,
                                               ByVal _planDescription As String,
                                               ByVal _rowId As Integer)
```

**Data Access Layer**

```
Public Shared Function UpdateManualAdjustment(ByVal _refYear As Integer,
                                           ByVal _refMonth As String,
                                           ByVal _branchCode As String,
                                           ByVal _employeeCode As String,
                                           ByVal _policyNumber As Integer,
                                           ByVal _extraPolicyType As String,
                                           ByVal _premium As Integer,
                                           ByVal _case As Decimal,
                                           ByVal _planCode As String,
                                           ByVal _planDescription As String,
                                           ByVal _rowId As Integer)


    Return Company.Applications.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(Company.Applications.Data.ConnectionStrings.getProductionEngine, _
                                                                CommandType.StoredProcedure, _
                                                                "BR_NAME_MANUAL_ADJUSTMENTS_UPDATE", _
                                                                New SqlClient.SqlParameter("year", _refYear),
                                                                New SqlClient.SqlParameter("month", _refMonth),
                                                                New SqlClient.SqlParameter("branchCode", _branchCode),
                                                                New SqlClient.SqlParameter("employeeCode", _employeeCode),
                                                                New SqlClient.SqlParameter("policyNumber", _policyNumber),
                                                                New SqlClient.SqlParameter("extraPolicyType", _extraPolicyType),
                                                                New SqlClient.SqlParameter("premium", _premium),
                                                                New SqlClient.SqlParameter("case", _case),
                                                                New SqlClient.SqlParameter("planCode", _planCode),
                                                                New SqlClient.SqlParameter("planDescription", _planDescription),
                                                                New SqlClient.SqlParameter("rowId", _rowId))

End Function
```

**.ASPX File**

```
<asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCase" runat="server" Width="90px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCase" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCase"
                            ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Insert"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revCase" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Decimal Field"
                            ControlToValidate="txtCase" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^\d+([,\.]\d{1,2})?$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </asp:TableCell>
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MY_STORED_PROCEDURE]
    @year INT,
    @month VARCHAR(50),
    @branchCode VARCHAR(50),
    @employeeCode VARCHAR (50),
    @policyNumber BIGINT,
    @extraPolicyType VARCHAR(50),
    @premium DECIMAL,
    @case DECIMAL,
    @rowId INT,
    @planCode VARCHAR(5),
    @planDescription VARCHAR(50)

AS
BEGIN   
    UPDATE BR_NAME_MANUAL_ADJUSTMENTS
    SET RefYear = @year,
        RefMonth = @month,
        BranchCode = @branchCode,
        EmployeeCode = @employeeCode,
        PolicyNumber = @policyNumber,
        ExtraPolicyType = @extraPolicyType,
        Premium = @premium,
        Cases = @case,
        PlanCode = @planCode,
        PolicyPlanDescription = @planDescription
    WHERE RowId = @rowId
END
```

Comment: There is almost certainly something wrong with the code between the line that you posted and the save.  You are almost certainly converting to an `Integer` somewhere.  We can only guess at where that might be without seeing the relevant code.

Comment: With regards to your edit, there's no point converting a `String` to a `Decimal` and then back to a `String` again. If that code even compiles then you must have `Option Strict Off`, which you should remedy immediately.

Comment: Ok changed. Whole code posted.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be an issue in the code you posted, which suggests that it is inside the `InsertNewAdjustment` and/or `UpdateManualAdjustment` methods. Have you actually debugged the code and stepped into those to track the value?

Comment: Yes. If I put 1.5 into the textbox and debug, the value taken in is shown as 1.5D, in my GridView and in my database, 2.0 is finally saved instead of 1.5.

Comment: That's not what I asked.  Have you stepped into those two methods for which you have not shown the implementation?  There's nothing obvious in the code you've shown but there's also no reason that a `Decimal` value should be spontaneously rounded so the issue is almost certainly in that code, which you haven't shown us and provided no indication that you have debugged.

Comment: Updated the code with all definitions of the UpdateManualAdjustment method. I'll step through it right now see what happens and I'll get back.

Comment: Changed the data type of _case in Business Layer and Data Access Layer from Integer to Decimal, but now the value saved is 1.0 and not 2.0. So now it's rounding downwards. Code updated.

Comment: Debugged and stepped through all code again. Value taken in is 1.5D but 1.00 is being saved to the database not sure why. _case holds 1.5D throughout whole process not sure what's going on.

Comment: Just a note. If I do a manual insert through SSMS into the table, it takes in 1.5 just fine. (Saves as 1.50 which is acceptable).

Comment: And what if you execute the sproc in SSMS?

Comment: Very good suggestion as I had INT. I changed it to decimal and now the number rounds upwards again. 1.5 becomes 2.0. Code updated with stored proc.

Comment: I'll test proc now on its own. Give me a sec.

Comment: and the downvote was because?

Comment: It wasn't from me, but I suspect that it's because the issue turned out to be something that you should have checked before you posted in the first place and certainly long before it was suggested as an answer.  My first comment said that there was something wrong somewhere after the line you posted so you should have checked every step the value went through after that.  The SQL code is what does the actual insertion so it should have been an obvious place to check.

Comment: Ok that's fair enough. I'm just asking so I know for later on. It would be a good idea if for every downvote a little comment was added stating why we've been downvoted so that we, as new users, know what we've done wrong. I think it makes sense and that it's constructive. After all, even though we read through SO's rules, we can't remember all of them, we'll have to learn as we go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Stored Procedure, and make sure the "case" Parameter have datatype decimal(18,2)

Comment: Changed parameter type in stored procedure to Decimal AND added the (18,2). Works.